# Node.js JsonParser custom function "cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, discord.js

I am trying to make a JSON function that will be able to return parsed data from JSON files for multiple other functions without needing to rewrite the same code over and over. Here is the function I have, along with a variable:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
function jsonParser(jsonFile) {
    fs.readFile(jsonFile,
        function (err, data) {
            var jsonData = data;
            var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
            return jsonParsed;
        })
};
```

When I insert a `console.log` into this function for testing, it returns the data from `jsonParsed` without any issue. Here is one example of how+where this function will be used:

```js
msg.channel.send(jsonParser('package.json').version);
```

And here is the JSON file this is loading from:

```
{
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "description": "Mírre from The Autorise Domain recreated as a Discord bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple ways to try to get the "version" data, but it keeps returning the same "*cannot read property of 'version' of undefined*" message every time. I would like to be able to push the object data through `msg.channel.send()`, but that isn't happening -- as if the program has already wiped the object out of memory by the time it reaches the send function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**:
The function is being called within a `Discord.Client()` message function. After defining the bot as `const bot = new Discord.Client()`, the command that `jsonParser` is used in is called from a large `bot.on('message'...` function. From here, there is a switch-case of multiple commands someone can give the bot, with one of them being used to find the bot's version; this is where `jsonParser` is being called from.

Comment: You aren't actually returning the json from your function. You are returning it from the callback of readFile but you aren't returning from the parent function so you're going to keep getting undefined until you return from the parent.

Comment: because you're using callback for reading file, you should use promises instead: `fs.promises.readfile(jsonFile)` and `msg.channel.send((await jsonParser('package.json')).version);`

Comment: @HoangDao that seems to be going on the right track, but not entirely. Now I'm being told `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for jsonParser in the msg line.

Comment: the error seems strange, are you missing something?

Comment: @Freerey ah, you're missing `}` at the end of your json file I think

Comment: @HoangDao that's not the issue; that was just a typo when pasting the json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, changing to `fs.promises` works without problem:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function jsonParser(jsonFile) {
  const data = await fs.promises.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, jsonFile));

  var jsonData = data.toString('utf-8');
  var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  return jsonParsed;
};

(async function (jsonFile) {
  const data = await jsonParser(jsonFile);
  console.log(data.version);
})('./test.json').catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Because this code is being used for a Discord bot, make sure that the `.on` function for the client is using an `async()` like so:

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client();
...
bot.on('message', async(msg) => {...}
```

Comment: There seems to be some sort of discrepancy between sync/async functions. When I put the `async function (jsonFile)` part in parentheses, I don't get any data back and the debugger does not show any errors, but simply throwing those lines of code inside without wrapping in an async function causes the error `await is only valid in async function` to appear.
To help better understand what kind of function this is working in, I will update the question with some more code.

Comment: you're missing the `async` declaration on you function, if you're using discord, it should be something like `bot.on('message', async () => {<your logic of await reading jsonParser will be here>});`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I edited the answer a little to clarify how this would work on a Discord bot and now it's working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing in the JSON is changing during execution (which it shouldn't in the case of package.json), you could just go ahead and use require.

```
const { version } = require('./package.json');

...

msg.channel.send(version);
```